# FlipClock js countdown timer with webpack

Tags: javascript, flipclock

I am working on a simple countdown timer from 1:00 minutes to 00:00, the thing is that I  have to use the flipclock.js package manager, if I add new Date as second argument to FlipClock is works but when I try to add integer like :
new FlipClock(el,60) - for example, to countdown from 1 to 0 , I get an error **getTime is not defined**

I hope you understand me.

Thanks in advance

```
import FlipClock from 'flipclock';

const el = document.querySelector('.clock');

const clock = new FlipClock(el,new Date {
    countdown: true,
    face: 'MinuteCounter',
});
```

Comment: Can it be possible it's not meant to work with integers? Why not to work with vanilla DOM API?

Comment: @JuhoVepsäläinen I tried but maybe I am missing something